# Named service won't start - seems to be caching errors

Tags: centos, services

When I try to restart / start the `named` service, it keeps failing.

```
service named restart
```

Results in:-

```
Stopping named:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting named:
Error in named configuration:
/etc/named.conf:2: missing ';' before '}'
                                                           [FAILED]

service named start
```

Results in:-

```
Starting named:
Error in named configuration:
/etc/named.conf:2: missing ';' before '}'
                                                           [FAILED]
```

The thing is, even if `named.conf` contains no syntax errors or even if the file doesn't exist at all, I'm still getting this error preventing me from starting the service.

Currently trying with a `named.conf` containing the following:-

```
options {
listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; };
};
```

And checking the syntax of `named.conf` using

```
named-checkconf /etc/named.conf
```

Results in no errors. Yet when starting the service, I still get the above error.

I can't see any other errors in the logs relating to this and don't really know where to get to the bottom of this. Any ideas?

(Even reverting back to the `named.conf` file that was in place before I stopped the service returns the same error now and this was previously running fine).

Contents on `init.d/named` can be seen at this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/9kqAuj8y).

CentOS 6.4 - Linux version 2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b8.bsys.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu May 16 20:59:36 UTC 2013

## Update

```
bash -x /etc/init.d/named start
```

Snippet from results possibly of relevance?

```
+ echo 'Error in named configuration:'
Error in named configuration:
+ echo '/etc/named.conf:2: missing '\'';'\'' before '\''}'\'''
/etc/named.conf:2: missing ';' before '}'
+ failure
+ local rc=0
+ '[' color '!=' verbose -a -z '' ']'
+ echo_failure
+ '[' color = color ']'
+ echo -en '\033[60G'
                                                           + echo -n '['
[+ '[' color = color ']'
+ echo -en '\033[0;31m'
+ echo -n FAILED
FAILED+ '[' color = color ']'
+ echo -en '\033[0;39m'
+ echo -n ']'
]+ echo -ne '\r'
+ return 1
+ '[' -x /bin/plymouth ']'
+ /bin/plymouth --details
+ return 0
+ echo
```

Comment: have you watch the script that probably exists in `/etc/init.d/named` ? the errors probably come from there

Comment: Even though it specifically states `/etc/named.conf` file? (I've run a `named-checkconfig` on `/etc/init.d/named` as well but nothing flagged that would prevent service from starting). Thanks.

Comment: @GeoffJackson-zigojacko yes, the service command does not execute /etc/named.conf it probably executes /etc/init.d/named, and that you cannot check with `named-checkconf` as it is not a `named` config file.

Comment: @GeoffJackson-zigojacko what is your distribution? (Add a tag to the question).

Comment: I see, thanks @Anthon (distro CentOS 6.4 - full version added above). What would be the process to check for issues in `/etc/init.d/named` please?

Comment: @GeoffJackson-zigojacko copyt paste the content in your question or just open it and see where the error can happen to identify the problem, most of the time this is just a bash script. you can also tries `bash -x /etc/init.d/named start` to debug the script

Comment: Thanks @Kiwy - will try the bash debug. Content can be seen at [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/9kqAuj8y) too.

Comment: @GeoffJackson-zigojacko And if the debug doesn't work, you can always insert some print statements in the scripts to narrow down where in the /etc/init.d/named script the message is generated.

Comment: Managed to resolve by fluke (see my answer). Not entirely sure why this fixed it /was causing the error though. Thanks for both of your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I managed to resolve this by changing one line in `/etc/init.d/named`:-

Line 29 in `/etc/init.d/named` changed from...

```
named='named'
```

To...

```
named='named -u named'
```

Then service would start back up again without issue. Nothing like a misleading error message!

Sigh.

Comment: it's nice that you find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

When I had the following issue then we checked the two lines.

```
-bash-4.1# service named start
Starting named: 
Error in named configuration:
zone localhost.localdomain/IN: loaded serial 0
zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 0
zone 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
zone 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
dns_master_load: acme.co.za.hosts:337: unexpected end of line
dns_master_load: acme.co.za.hosts:336: unexpected end of input
zone inet.co.za/IN: loading from master file acme.co.za.hosts failed: unexpected end of input
zone inet.co.za/IN: not loaded due to errors.
_default/acme.co.za/IN: unexpected end of input
```

I fixed up the entry for the `dns_master_load: acme.co.za.hosts:337:` unexpected end of line. It was missing the IP address.